# Java: Find list of primes less than n (where n is a BigNum)

Tags: java, primes

This code prints out only 2, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with my Linked List implementation. Starting out I just want to find the primes less than 100.

A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. A natural number greater than 1 that is not a prime number is called a composite number.

```
import java.math.*;
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;
class Node {
    BigInteger data;
    Node small;
    Node large;
    public Node(BigInteger data) {
        this.data = data;
        small = null;
        large = null;
    }
}
class TreeList {
    public static void join(Node a, Node b) {
        a.large = b;
        b.small = a;
    }
    public static Node append(Node a, Node b) {
        if (a == null) return(b);
        if (b == null) return(a);
        Node aLast = a.small;
        Node bLast = b.small;
        join(aLast, b);
        join(bLast, a);   
        return(a);
    }
    public static Node treeToList(Node root) {
        if (root == null) return (null);
        Node aList = treeToList(root.small);
        Node bList = treeToList(root.large);
        root.small = root;
        root.large = root;
        aList = append(aList, root);
        aList = append(aList, bList);   
        return(aList);
    }
    public static void treeInsert(Node root, BigInteger newData) {
        if (newData.compareTo(root.data) == 0) {
            if (root.small != null) treeInsert(root.small, newData);
            else root.small = new Node(newData);
        }
        else {
            if (root.large != null) treeInsert(root.large, newData);
            else root.large = new Node(newData);
        }
    }
    public static void printTree(Node root) {
        if (root == null) return;
        printTree(root.small);
        System.out.print(root.data.toString());
        printTree(root.large);
    }
    public static void printList(Node head) {
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data.toString() + " ");
            current = current.large;
            if (current == head) break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger count = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger myPrime = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        Node root = new Node(myPrime);
        Node head = treeToList(root);

        boolean isPrime;

        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("100");

        for (BigInteger i = three; count.compareTo(n) == 0; i = i.add(two)) {
            isPrime = true;
            for (BigInteger j = three; (j.multiply(j)).compareTo(i) == 0 && isPrime; j = j.add(two))
                if (i.mod(j) == BigInteger.ZERO) isPrime = false;
            if (isPrime) {
                count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);   
                myPrime = i;
                if (myPrime.compareTo(n) == 0) treeInsert(root, myPrime);
            }
        }
        printList(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to be little more sure about what the problem is. If you think it's your list - prove it.

Comment: Why are all of these variables `BigInteger`s?

Comment: Think about "count.compareTo(n) == 0", this is a conditions and its always false. It will never enter into for loop.

Comment: @PaulBoddington The topic is to find a list of primes less than n where n is a BigNumber. Therefore, the for loop might have to be really big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop simply not running, because it return `false` on `count.compareTo(n) == 0`.

For loop, only runs when the 2nd statement returns true.

Your 2nd for loop is buggy as well.